# Error with import mysql.connector on Python3.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm on Python3 and I get an error when I import mysql.connector in my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 30, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from . import version
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

This is strange because all was working fine and then I don't know what I did to get this error...
I tried to uninstall and reinstall mysql-connector-python with pip, I also tried `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall mysql-connector-python` but nothing fixed my problem...
However I can import mysql.

Can someone help me please ? Thx !

Comment: I have seen this error before: when the SD card of a Raspberry Pi failed.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it's not related to python, I have several problems now, I can't open a web browser, ssh doesn't work, ifconfig gives me errors...